# How to select departure and return date on the calendar of Booking.com by using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm building a web scraper using Selenium Python on Booking.com and I am stuck with calendar select dates. Here is my function code below. I am using a run.py and another external functions file. The date selection is not working I can choose two days from the same month but from two different months is not working

```
import Booking.constants as const
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import  By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os

class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:\Users\osama\Anaconda3", teardown=False) :
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.maximize_window()
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc, traceback):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()
        
    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL) 
        
    def choose_currency(self, currency=None):
        currency_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
            'button[data-modal-header-async-type="currencyDesktop"]'
            )
        currency_element.click()
        selected_currency = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
            f'a[data-modal-header-async-url-param="changed_currency=1&selected_currency={currency}"]'
              )
        selected_currency.click()
        
    def select_place_to_go(self, place_to_go):
        search_field = self.find_element(By.ID, 'ss')
        search_field.clear()
        search_field.send_keys(place_to_go)
        first_result = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li[data-i="0"').click()
        
    def select_dates(self, check_in_date, check_out_date):
        check_in_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'td[data-date="{check_in_date}"]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        all_dates = self.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bui-calendar']//tbody//td")
        for date in all_dates:
            if date.get_attribute("data-date") == f'{check_out_date}':
                date.click()
                time.sleep(4)
                break
```

Comment: what's happening currently with your code? is it giving error?

Comment: I have already selected currency and destination now I want to select check-in date and check out dates

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a partially efficient answer. All the answer I found to my question was in Java and the only answers in python were taking the approach of selecting the XPath of the whole calendar and then writing a for loop or while loop with a fixed date. In the below code I just select the next button on the calendar which I can custom clicking it more than once easily depending on the dates I want to choose then select the check-in date and the checkout date separately and voila it worked I know it is not the best solution as I am still a beginner but it fulfilled what I need from the scrap. Please be kind and see my solution and give me your feedback I changed the function in the code I put above with the one below.

```
def select_dates(self, check_in_date, check_out_date):
        next_button = self.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-bui-ref="calendar-next"]')
        next_button.click()
        check_in_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'td[data-date="{check_in_date}"]')
        check_in_element.click()
        check_out_element = self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'td[data-date="{check_out_date}"]')
        check_out_element.click()
```